# Clear a field when the user starts filling a form

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I have a view with a form in it:

```
<form asp-controller="UrlP" asp-action="RegisterInput" method="post"> 
Url:  <input asp-for="Url" />
<br />
<button type="submit">Go!</button>
```

and, on the same view, I have a result from the previous submission:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Result))
{
    <div class="result">The result is: @Model.Result</div>
}
```

How can I make the div above (class 'result') disappear as soon a the user starts typing in the form?

To give some context, the app is a single page where you provide a url and you get a result below and I would like to clear the result as soon as a new url is entered.

Comment: I've removed the asp.net-core tag as the question is unrelated to ASP.NET Core but is about javascript/html and client sided issue (happens in browser not on server)

Comment: the solution will involve JS, but since the form is started through asp tags, I would have hoped there would be some asp callback when the form starts to get edited for example (I'm new to asp)

Comment: @Tseng: I have included the asp-net-core tag. This issue does not need any front end tech interference and can be handled from the asp code

Comment: @Tushar: You clearly didn't read the question. _How can I make the div above (class 'result') disappear as soon a the user starts typing in the form?_ He clearly asks how to hide a div-Tag when user starts typing, with emphasis on **start typing**. This this happens in the browser and can only be handled client sided, means JavaScript. This is a typical client-sided validation scenario

Comment: @Thomas: It's unrelated with ASP.NET Core unless you are referring to `asp-validation-summary` and `asp-validation-for` tag helpers but from your code it doesn't look like you are looking for model validation, so these won't work unless the shown field is related to the (view)model validation

Comment: Uhm @Tseng let OP reply. I think this is kinda paradox. We may be correct and wrong at the same time. If that would be the case will delete my answer and tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using ASP.net Core, it can be handled from the Action and Model State

So after the post, just clear your ModelState and return view like :

```
ModelState.Clear();
return View(<some View>);
```

Comment: That's not what OP is asking. He asked on when the **user starts typing**

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  // attach onkeypress event handler to all text inputs
  document.querySelectorAll('form [type=text]').forEach(function (input) {
    input.onkeypress = hideResult;
  });
};

function hideResult () {
  var result = document.querySelector('.result');
  // remove result if it exist
  if (result) {
      result.parentNode.removeChild(result);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="result">The result is: @Model.Result</div>

<form>
  <input type="text" value=""><br>
  <input type="text" value="">
</form>
```